# Dump all spatialite tables to shp and dbf

Tags: shapefile, export, spatialite, dbf

Given a spatialite database i want to export/dump all tables to shapefile (or dbf for those without geometry).

I want to do it programatically so acceptable solutions will be using a (bash) command line tool like `spatialite`, `ogr2ogr`, ... or Python.

Is there a command that export all database in one shot or should i iterate over each layer and dumping it individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL is great and that's why it will automatically export layers one by one if you tell `ogr2ogr` to convert a multi-layer file to a single-layer format. The destination data source will automatically become a directory and inside you will get the single layers one by one.

To include all tables, you have to specify the [config option `SQLITE_LIST_ALL_TABLES`](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#SQLITE_LIST_ALL_TABLES) set to `yes`.

```
$ ogrinfo --config SQLITE_LIST_ALL_TABLES yes test.spatialite 
INFO: Open of `test.spatialite.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.
1: test (Point)
2: ElementaryGeometries (None)
3: SpatialIndex (None)
4: geom_cols_ref_sys (None)
5: geometry_columns (None)
6: geometry_columns_auth (None)
7: geometry_columns_field_infos (None)
8: geometry_columns_statistics (None)
9: geometry_columns_time (None)
10: idx_test_GEOMETRY (None)
11: idx_test_GEOMETRY_node (None)
12: idx_test_GEOMETRY_parent (None)
13: idx_test_GEOMETRY_rowid (None)
14: non_spatial (None)
15: spatial_ref_sys (None)
16: spatial_ref_sys_all (None)
17: spatial_ref_sys_aux (None)
18: spatialite_history (None)
19: sql_statements_log (None)
20: sqlite_sequence (None)
21: vector_layers (None)
22: vector_layers_auth (None)
23: vector_layers_field_infos (None)
24: vector_layers_statistics (None)
25: views_geometry_columns (None)
26: views_geometry_columns_auth (None)
27: views_geometry_columns_field_infos (None)
28: views_geometry_columns_statistics (None)
29: virts_geometry_columns (None)
30: virts_geometry_columns_auth (None)
31: virts_geometry_columns_field_infos (None)
32: virts_geometry_columns_statistics (None)
```

`$ ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out file.gpkg`

```
$ ls -1 out/
ElementaryGeometries.dbf
geom_cols_ref_sys.dbf
geometry_columns_auth.dbf
geometry_columns.dbf
geometry_columns_field_infos.dbf
geometry_columns_statistics.dbf
geometry_columns_time.dbf
idx_test_GEOMETRY.dbf
idx_test_GEOMETRY_node.dbf
idx_test_GEOMETRY_parent.dbf
idx_test_GEOMETRY_rowid.dbf
non_spatial.dbf
SpatialIndex.dbf
spatialite_history.dbf
spatial_ref_sys_all.dbf
spatial_ref_sys_aux.dbf
spatial_ref_sys.dbf
sqlite_sequence.dbf
sql_statements_log.dbf
test.dbf
test.prj
test.shp
test.shx
vector_layers_auth.dbf
vector_layers.dbf
vector_layers_field_infos.dbf
vector_layers_statistics.dbf
views_geometry_columns_auth.dbf
views_geometry_columns.dbf
views_geometry_columns_field_infos.dbf
views_geometry_columns_statistics.dbf
virts_geometry_columns_auth.dbf
virts_geometry_columns.dbf
virts_geometry_columns_field_infos.dbf
virts_geometry_columns_statistics.dbf
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That only exports spatial tables and not alphanumeric only tables. I try with https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115638/4177 but that also export indexes, `idx_xxx`, internal views like `virts_geometry_columns.dbf`, ...

Comment: I added that config option now, sorry for missing it. Hm, could you add that requirement to your question? Right now my answer fully satisfies it.

Comment: It was already in the question `(or dbf for those without geometry)`:). Thanks for update your answer. I accept it.

Comment: That part was and I had missed it. I meant the other tables you want to not have. We could just add a call to rm for those files ;)